# How to count as week request to fill in at my order history

Tags: google-sheets

Red column is the result I wanted to get which based on the quantity get the date I wanted.
[image]

Comment: Hmm which details because i don't know how explain what was I want, the red area I highlight was result I want to see it. But now was I manually key in at there

Answer (score 1):

Put it in `B2`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,SUMIF(H:H,A2:A,G:G)))
```

---

Alternative:

Put it in `A2`:

```
=QUERY(G:H,"select H,sum(G) where H is not null group by H label H '',sum(G) ''",1)
```

Reference:

- [SUMIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583?hl=en)
- [QUERY function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)

Comment: When i put the A2 it showing error Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: AVG_SUM_ONLY_NUMERIC why

Comment: Please share you sheet.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17RnLN7qLwFXwxdZO3ue7GCOIYq5_FyJHgvzaKBWGp4c/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The columns are different from that in the old screenshot you provided. Please change `H` and `G` to `H` and `I` yourself.

Comment: Sorry i just reupload the correct image the tab at Copy of Sheet2